# Webpack: Unable to find module with ID: main -- (Aurelia App)

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, entry-point

TLDR: *Aurelia* app, bundled with *webpack*, can't load in browser - console shows error: `can't find module with id: main`. I think that means it can't find the entrypoint. Running out of things to try.

---

- I work on an **Aurelia** application.
- We use **webpack** for bundling our front-end code.
- It all worked great until the past couple days. (recently we added **aurelia-dialog**, which worked fine, but we had to do some npm updates to be able to get it to work, etc.)
- There were a several npm dependency issues that needed resolving, but I got them eventually...
- One *particularly* annoying one was that gulp used to be included in our package.json as `"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0` but I guess that git branch was removed, so between that and whatever other npm issues, they all needed to be updated to `"gulp": "4.0"` which is chill - apart from it then causing us to then go and have to start the horrendous long train of npm dependency resolutions.
- Now, however, I'm stuck at at point where there are no errors with the npm packages, nor errors coming from webpack's compilation process, nor any tslint errors. **However**, the app is broken, and even in other branches which haven't been touched, it's also having issues.

The error is:

> Error: Unable to find module with ID: main
>
> at WebpackLoader. (https://localhost:44399/dist/app.bundle.js?v=18.11.05&v=QnXnhS1zNjvTNWq1CN7QzBCr2ti1BVIVEjGB_ewbuj0:9435:35)
>
> at step (https://localhost:44399/dist/app.bundle.js?v=18.11.05&v=QnXnhS1zNjvTNWq1CN7QzBCr2ti1BVIVEjGB_ewbuj0:9296:23)

If I'm understanding correctly (I'm not the developer who set this app up, and he's no longer around), the "main" being referenced in the error comes from the `aurelia-app="main"` attribute within the `<body>` element in `wwwroot/dist/index.html` :

(see bottom for directory stucture)

## index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aurelia Navigation Skeleton</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

the value "main", I believe is supposed to reference the `src/main.ts`:

(I've tried changing it to: `main.ts`, `src/main.ts`, `src/main`, `../../src/main.ts`, etc -- none of them worked or even changed the error message, which makes me feel like that's not the right place to be looking.)

## main.ts

```
// we want font-awesome to load as soon as possible to show the fa-spinner
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework'
import environment from './environment';
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

// remove if you don't want a Promise polyfill (remove also from webpack.config.js)
Bluebird.config({ warnings: { wForgottenReturn: false } });

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-dialog'))
    //.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'))
    //.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-ui-virtualization')) 
    .globalResources(
        [
            //Converters
            PLATFORM.moduleName('converters/decimal-format'), 
            PLATFORM.moduleName('converters/unit-selection-format'), 
            PLATFORM.moduleName('converters/sort'), 
            PLATFORM.moduleName('converters/date-format'),

            //Custom Element Registrations
            //base-level components (standalone)
            //PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/table-cell-text-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/text-div-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/icon-button-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/checkbox-div-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/range-selector-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/unit-selector-element'),

            //mid-level components (groupings/dependent on others)
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/content-header-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/table-configurable-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/table-tiered-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/grid-selector-element'),

            //high-level components (groups of mid-level)
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/grid-selector-group-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/dropdown-select-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/alert-element'),

            //Rate Components 
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/base-charge-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/tiered-rate-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/tiered-per-unit-charge-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/rate-component-element'),
            PLATFORM.moduleName('components/custom-elements/meter-charge-element')
        ]);


  // Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  // aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-animator-css'));
  // if the css animator is enabled, add swap-order="after" to all router-view elements

  // Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  // aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-html-import-template-loader'));

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
    }



  aurelia.start().then(() => {aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app'))});
}
```

which, I'm fairly sure, has nothing wrong in it - because it was working fine at the end of last week and hasn't changed since.

one noteworthy thing is that we altered the **ModuleDependenciesPlugin** section in our **webpack.config.js**. We added an entry: `"aurelia-dialog": ['./aurelia-dialog', './ux-dialog-header', './ux-dialog-body', -dialog-footer', './attach-focus']` which was necessary to get the custom components from aurelia-dialog to load (see below).
This change didn't break the app initially. It was working fine for about a week, I'd say?

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || [];
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
  condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig);

// primary config:
const title = 'Aurelia Navigation Skeleton';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist');
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
];

module.exports = ({production, server, extractCss, coverage, analyze} = {}) => ({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
    vendor: ['bluebird'],
  },
  mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].chunk.js'
  },
  performance: { hints: false },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
      // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
        use: extractCss ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: cssRules
        }) : ['style-loader', ...cssRules],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
        // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
        // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
        use: cssRules
      },
      {test: /\.js\.map$/,  loader: 'ignore-loader' },
      {test: /\.ts\.orig$/,  loader: 'ignore-loader' },
      {test: /\.html\.orig$/,  loader: 'ignore-loader' },
      {test: /\.tst$/,  loader: 'ignore-loader' },
      { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      //{ test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader' },
      // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
      { test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise' },
      // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
      // load these fonts normally, as files:
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
      ...when(coverage, {
        test: /\.[jt]s$/i, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        include: srcDir, exclude: [/\.{spec,test}\.[jt]s$/i],
        enforce: 'post', options: { esModules: true },
      })
    ]
  },
    plugins: [
        //new AureliaWebpackPlugin({
        //    includeSubModules: [{
        //        moduleId: 'aurelia-dialog'
        //    },
        //    ],
        //    contextMap: {
        //        'aurelia-dialog': 'node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/commonjs/aurelia-dialog.js'
        //    }
        //}),
    new AureliaPlugin({includeAll: "src"}),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': 'bluebird'
    }),
    new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
        'aurelia-testing': ['./compile-spy', './view-spy'],
        "aurelia-dialog": ['./aurelia-dialog', './ux-dialog-header', './ux-dialog-body',
            './ux-dialog-footer', './attach-focus']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.ejs',
      minify: production ? {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      } : undefined,
      metadata: {
        // available in index.ejs //
        title, server, baseUrl
      }
    }),
    ...when(extractCss, new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: production ? '[contenthash].css' : '[id].css',
      allChunks: true
    })),
    ...when(production, new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'static/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' }])),
    ...when(analyze, new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
  ]
});
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "webui",
  "description": "An Aurelia client application.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "???",
    "url": "???"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.38.3",
    "aurelia-animator-css": "^1.0.4",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.2.0",
    "aurelia-dialog": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "^1.3.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "core-decorators": "^0.2.0",
    "lit-html": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.105",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.23",
    "@types/pikaday": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "aurelia-cli": "^0.35.1",
    "aurelia-loader-nodejs": "^1.0.1",
    "aurelia-pal-nodejs": "^1.0.0-beta.3.2.0",
    "aurelia-protractor-plugin": "^1.0.6",
    "aurelia-testing": "^1.0.0-beta.4.0.0",
    "aurelia-tools": "^2.0.0",
    "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "cypress": "^3.1.0",
    "d3": "^5.1.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.4.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "gulp": "4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "iterall": "^1.2.2",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "jest-cli": "^23.0.0-alpha.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
    "nps": "^5.8.2",
    "nps-utils": "^1.5.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "opn": "^5.3.0",
    "pikaday": "^1.7.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.44.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "through2": "^2.0.3",
    "tinymce": "^4.7.11",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "uglify-js": "^3.3.15",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-fs": "^3.0.2",
    "wait-on": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "latest",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.2",
    "wnumb": "^1.1.0",
    "wormhole.js": "^0.10.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "\\.spec\\.(ts|js)x?$",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/jest-pretest.ts"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "!**/*.spec.{js,ts}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/test/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/test/coverage-jest",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "html"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "nps test",
    "webpack-watch": "webpack --watch --info-verbosity verbose",
    "webpack-display-errors": "webpack --display-error-details",
    "compile": "tsc -w",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p cypress  -w"
  },
  "main": "dist/app.bundle.js",
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "compile-tests",
      "compile",
      "webpack-watch"
    ]
  }
}
```

## aurelia.json

```
  "name": "WebUIFinal",
  "type": "project:application",
  "bundler": {
    "id": "webpack",
    "displayName": "Webpack"
  },
  "build": {
    "options": {
      "server": "dev",
      "extractCss": "prod",
      "coverage": false
    }
  },
  "platform": {
    "id": "aspnetcore",
    "displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
    "port": 8080,
    "hmr": false,
    "open": false,
    "output": "wwwroot/dist"
  },
  "loader": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None"
  },
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "typescript",
    "displayName": "TypeScript",
    "fileExtension": ".ts"
  },
  "markupProcessor": {
    "id": "minimum",
    "displayName": "Minimal Minification",
    "fileExtension": ".html"
  },
  "cssProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".css"
  },
  "editor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None"
  },
  "unitTestRunner": [
    {
      "id": "jest",
      "displayName": "Jest"
    }
  ],
  "integrationTestRunner": {
    "id": "protractor",
    "displayName": "Protractor"
  },
  "paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "resources",
    "elements": "resources/elements",
    "attributes": "resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "resources/binding-behaviors"
  },
  "testFramework": {
    "id": "jasmine",
    "displayName": "Jasmine"
  }
}
```

---

My coworker and I have both spent the past couple days on this trying to get it figured out - so any help is appreciated.

I've tried resetting all the changes (including going back to before aurelia-dialog was added), have tried changing the aurelia-app attribute's value. Cleaned & rebuilt a few times. Restarted the computed. Re-cloned the repository....

---

The directory structure is

```
WebUIFinal/
├── wwwroot/
│   └── dist/
│        ├── index.html
│        ├── 0.chunk.js
│        ├── ...
│        ├── vendor.bundle.js
│        └── app.bundle.js
├── aurelia-project/
│   └── aurelia.json
├── src/
│   ├── app.ts
│   └── main.ts
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
(plus a bunch of other stuff, of course -- this is just what I deemed relevant)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

After a debugging session, the issue with `module with ID: main not found` was simply resolved by changing Webpack AureliaPlugin to its simplest form:

```
plugins: [
  new AureliaPlugin()
]
```

As the built code is in a format that Webpack can understand easily, no need for any configuration.

Also, it'd be easier for debugging. if `configure` function in main is wrapped in a try catch, or `catch(ex =>)` of promise, so you can see any issues coming up, instead of a silently fail and a forever loading screen.

---

With the latest release of dialog, you should not have to manually include `ModuleDependenciesPlugin` for dialog anymore, as it uses dynamic import API, which is understood by Webpack naturally. So I would suggest going back to your original one, and delete that configuration.

```js
new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
    'aurelia-testing': ['./compile-spy', './view-spy'],
    // "aurelia-dialog": ['./aurelia-dialog', './ux-dialog-header', './ux-dialog-body', './ux-dialog-footer', './attach-focus']
})
```

Comment: :\ appreciate the suggestion, unfortunately it still won't load. will try that again once this issues is resolved though cause that'd be handy if we didn't need that line there.

Comment: It's a simple fix, and you shouldn't have any issues with it. If needed, you can PM me on discourse or gitter and I can help.

Comment: I believe you contribute to aurelia, right? are you able to tell if this issue I'm having of the app being unable to load is an issue with our webpack or with how we're using aurelia? I think one of the issues for me at this point is that I don't even know where the problem is coming from

Comment: It could be from the way you use them together. I think it's just some simple tweaks, just something is missing, but StackOverflow isn't good for lengthy debugging session, so I suggest doing it somewhere else